# Push Notifications not showing up in foreground (when the app is closed) in react-native-firebase

Tags: push-notification, react-native-firebase

React-native-Firebase push notifications can't be shown foreground, when the app was closed. If the app is open, then there is no issue with push notifications, they are showing fine.

```
async createNotificationListeners() {

this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
    const { title, body } = notification;

    const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
        sound: 'default',
        show_in_foreground: true,
    }) 
 firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotification)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: Is this happening in Android or iOS?

Comment: The problem  in Android

Comment: here my AndroidManifest.xml  file permissions:                                                        uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

Comment: <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

Comment: <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService"/>
    <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>

Comment: <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
              android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much info, but if you are on Android you need to setup [notifications 
channels as per this documentation](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/notifications/android-channels.md)

```
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      "main_notification_channel",
      "Main notification Channel",
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    ).setDescription("A natural description of the channel");
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

Comment: Yes!. your right,but i'm already added "notification channel " in the createNotificationListeners function:                                                                           
here my listener function channel declaration:                                                                     const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
          "fcm_default_channel",
          "Firebase Alert",
          firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.High
        );
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);